# How can I fire some javascript code after my google custom search engine gets data back from server?

Tags: javascript, google-search-api

How can i use `setSearchCompleteCallback(object,method)` from this [doc](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference) with my code?

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '011685828559868923844:yxkryvmtqxm';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);

  })();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is like most apis it will have a callback querystring parameter

Set the callback

```
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx + "&callback=myCallback";
```

and the callback function

```
function myCallback (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

um... have you tried:

```
gcse.setSearchCompleteCallback(window, function(){ 
  alert('call complete');
});
```

the first argument (according to the docs) sets the 'context' for the callback function; in other words defines `this` within the scope of the callback. I picked the window object, but it could be anything.